# Get variable value from the outside of javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Unable to get the correct value from the variable in side the function.

Here is my code and always i am getting id as "two", i need the correct value that i passed to change function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
   $val='';
   global $val;
?>


function change(val){
  <?php //global $val;?>
      if (val=='one') {
         <?php $val='one';?>
      }
      if (val=='two') {
           <?php $val='two';?>
      }
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="change('one');" value="Change">

<div id="<?php echo $val;?>">
```

Comment: You should post the *rendered* html code. Such a mix of php/javascript is almost never a good idea.

Comment: It is looks like you try to mix using of client & server side code. This is really bad idea regardless of your goals.

Comment: Many apps are a mix of client & server code.  But they are written by engineers who know what is happening on the server and client.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `server-side-script` and `client-side-script` try it in `javascript` like,

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val='one'; // global value
    function change(){
        if (val=='one') {
           // your code for one
           val='two'; // change the value of val to two
        }
        else if (val=='two') {
            // your code for two
            val='one'; // again change val value
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName('changed_value')[0].id=val;
        document.getElementById(val).innerHTML=val;
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="change();" value="Change">
<div class="changed_value"></div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/xicexugi/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i need to print the "val" value in the html code like 

<div id="{val}"></div>

Comment: Try my updated answer and `demo`

Comment: I have done my task with the above suggestion's thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well the PHP code executed independent of your javascript code, which is only executed afterwards on the client side. So what your script does is executing this in PHP:

```
<?php
global $val;
$val='one';
$val='two';
?>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="<?php echo $val;?>">
```

and this is the code on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(val){

      if (val=='one') {
      }
      if (val=='two') {
      }
     }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="change('one');" value="Change">
```

So if you want to change an element you'll have to do it in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function change(val){
      var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

      if (val=='one') {
        el.id = 'one';
      }
      if (val=='two') {
        el.id = 'two';
      }
     }

</script>
<input type="button" onclick="change('one');" value="Change">

<div id="">
```

Comment: Is "" a valid HTML id? Would it be better to make it one or the other, and then use `document.getElementById` ?

Comment: I've kept my changes small and left the id uninitialised, because it is in the original question. But yes it's invalid.

And yes I'd also have a unique selector for the changed element (maybe a class).

I also don't see how changing the id could be useful ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps and working.